# Establishing a set identity involving collections

Tags: real-analysis

> $X \cup ( \bigcap_{A \in \mathscr{A}} A ) = \bigcap_{A \in \mathscr{A}
>  } (X \cup A ) $.

#### Attempt

We have $x \in X \cup ( \bigcap_{A \in \mathscr{A}} A )$ iff $x \in X$ or $x \in A $ for all $A \in \mathscr{A}$. This is true iff $x \in X \cup A $ for all $A \in \mathscr{A}$ and this holds iff $x \in \bigcap_{A \in \mathscr{A} } (X \cup A )$.

IS this corrrect? or Do I need to show more work? thanks

Comment: You have only proven that the left hand side is a subset of the right hand side. To prove equivalence, you must also show that the RHS is a subset of the LHS.

Comment: All is steps are iff: $x\in X\cup (\cap A)\leftrightarrow\forall A :x\in X\cup A\leftrightarrow x\in \cap (X\cup A) $